# GridView changes not showing in binded datatable

Tags: asp.net, .net, gridview, .net-2.0, asp.net-2.0

I have a GridView setup with I've tried to bind to DataTable .. I then make some changes to the GridView's values through the webpage .. Then I go behind the code of a button click, and see that the DataTable still has the old values in it ...

**ASPX Markup code for the GridView:**

```
<asp:gridview ID="ESBAndTSRValuesInputGridView" runat="server" ShowFooter="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Award ID" HeaderText="Award ID" Visible="false" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Award Name" HeaderText="Award Name" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ESB Value">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TSR Value">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
</asp:gridview>
```

**Initializing GridView data from code-behind of a button click:**

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Award ID", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Award Name", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ESB Value", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("TSR Value", typeof(string)));
DataRow[] PSPAwards =  dtAwards.Select("AWARDTYPE = 'PSP'");
foreach (DataRow dr in PSPAwards)
{
    dt.Rows.Add(dr["AWARDID"].ToString(), dr["AWARDNAME"].ToString(), "0", "100");
}
ViewState["ESBAndTSRValuesDataTable"] = dt;
ESBAndTSRValuesInputGridView.DataSource = dt;
ESBAndTSRValuesInputGridView.DataBind();
```

In the above code, you can see that I initialize the rows with default values 0 and 100 .. This is what I see during a debug event after making changes to these values from the webpage ..

How can I make the GridView automatically persist all changes done to it to its linked DataTable ?

I'm using .NET 2.0 Framework with VS2005 ..

Comment: Can someone please help me out here ?

Answer (score 1):

try this

your grid view

```
 <asp:gridview ID="ESBAndTSRValuesInputGridView" runat="server" ShowFooter="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="AwardID" HeaderText="Award ID" Visible="false" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="AwardName" HeaderText="Award Name" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ESBValue">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" Text='<%# Eval("ESBValue") %>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TSR Value">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" Text='<%# Eval("TSRValue") %>'  runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
</asp:gridview>
```

and in code behind

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("AwardID", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("AwardName", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ESBValue", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("TSRValue", typeof(string)));
        DataRow[] PSPAwards = dtAwards.Select("AWARDTYPE = 'PSP'");
        foreach (DataRow dr in PSPAwards)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(dr["AWARDID"].ToString(), dr["AWARDNAME"].ToString(), "0", "100");
        }
        ViewState["ESBAndTSRValuesDataTable"] = dt;
        ESBAndTSRValuesInputGridView.DataSource = dt;
        ESBAndTSRValuesInputGridView.DataBind();
```

Comment: Nope, that's not it .. No difference in output result .. :/

Comment: Tried it .. Still not working .. However, one problem I had was that the default values were not showing in the GridView before (i.e. 0 & 100 values were not showing) .. Now they showed up .. However, when I changed them and then went in codebehind, it was still 0 & 100 everywhere .. :(

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Framework fails the flush the DataSet/Datatable with the new data.

Try clearing the grid datasource.

```
ESBAndTSRValuesInputGridView.DataSource = null;
ESBAndTSRValuesInputGridView.DataBind();
ESBAndTSRValuesInputGridView.DataSource = dt;
ESBAndTSRValuesInputGridView.DataBind();
```

So your code will be

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Award ID", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Award Name", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ESB Value", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("TSR Value", typeof(string)));
DataRow[] PSPAwards =  dtAwards.Select("AWARDTYPE = 'PSP'");
foreach (DataRow dr in PSPAwards)
{
    dt.Rows.Add(dr["AWARDID"].ToString(), dr["AWARDNAME"].ToString(), "0", "100");
}
ViewState["ESBAndTSRValuesDataTable"] = dt;
ESBAndTSRValuesInputGridView.DataSource = null;
ESBAndTSRValuesInputGridView.DataBind();

ESBAndTSRValuesInputGridView.DataSource = dt;
ESBAndTSRValuesInputGridView.DataBind();
```

Comment: Excatly before re-biniding your grid.