# Why do I get empty strings when reading GridViewRow text values?

Tags: asp.net, .net, gridview, datatable, .net-2.0

Well since no one was able to determine why [my DataTable could not get the updated GridView data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364934), I'm now trying to directly get values from the GridView.

Problem now is that the text values I get from reading the GridViewRows are all empty strings.

**Here is my code:**

```
ASPX Markup code for the GridView:

<asp:gridview ID="ESBAndTSRValuesInputGridView" runat="server" ShowFooter="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="AwardID" HeaderText="Award ID" Visible="false" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="AwardName" HeaderText="Award Name" />
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ESBValue">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="ESBValue" Text='<%# Eval("ESBValue") %>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TSRValue">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TSRValue" Text='<%# Eval("TSRValue") %>'  runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:gridview>
```

**Initializing GridView data from code-behind of a button click:**

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("AwardID", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("AwardName", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ESBValue", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("TSRValue", typeof(string)));
DataRow[] PSPAwards = dtAwards.Select("AWARDTYPE = 'PSP'");
foreach (DataRow dr in PSPAwards)
{
    dt.Rows.Add(dr["AWARDID"].ToString(), dr["AWARDNAME"].ToString(), "0", "100");
}
ViewState["ESBAndTSRValuesDataTable"] = dt;
ESBAndTSRValuesInputGridView.DataSource = dt;
ESBAndTSRValuesInputGridView.DataBind();
```

**Trying to read the GridViewRow values:**

```
for (int rowCount = 0; rowCount < ESBAndTSRValuesInputGridView.Rows.Count; rowCount++)
{

    int cell0Val, cell1Val, cell2Val, cell3Val;

    //input text is blank for all:
    //TryParse returns false for all (because if I use Parse instead, exception occurs):

    Int32.TryParse(ESBAndTSRValuesInputGridView.Rows[rowCount].Cells[0].Text, out cell0Val);
    Int32.TryParse(ESBAndTSRValuesInputGridView.Rows[rowCount].Cells[1].Text, out cell1Val);
    Int32.TryParse(ESBAndTSRValuesInputGridView.Rows[rowCount].Cells[2].Text, out cell2Val);
    Int32.TryParse(ESBAndTSRValuesInputGridView.Rows[rowCount].Cells[3].Text, out cell3Val);

    int val1 = Int32.Parse(ESBAndTSRValuesInputGridView.Rows[rowCount].Cells[0].Text);
    int val2 = Int32.Parse(dr["AWARDID"].ToString());

    if (val1 == val2)
    {
        rowIndex = rowCount;
        break;
    }
}
```

So how can I get the actual text values when reading GridViewRows ?

I need the values of the BoundFields as well as the TextFields ..

And I'm using Visual Studio 2005 with .NET 2.0 Framework ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace your last cod block with this

you can not get directly value from textbox ..you have to find that control by id

gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="ESBAndTSRValuesInputGridView" runat="server" ShowFooter="true"
    AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Award Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblAwardID"  runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AwardID") %>' Style="display: none;"></asp:Label>
                <asp:Label ID="lblAwardName"  runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AwardName") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ESBValue">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="ESBValue" Text='<%# Eval("ESBValue") %>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TSRValue">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TSRValue" Text='<%# Eval("TSRValue") %>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

get values

```
 for (int rowCount = 0; rowCount < ESBAndTSRValuesInputGridView.Rows.Count; rowCount++)
        {

            int cell0Val, cell1Val, cell2Val, cell3Val;

            //input text is blank for all:
            //TryParse returns false for all (because if I use Parse instead, exception occurs):

            Int32.TryParse(((Label)ESBAndTSRValuesInputGridView.Rows[rowCount].FindControl("lblAwardID")).Text, out cell0Val);
            Int32.TryParse(((Label)ESBAndTSRValuesInputGridView.Rows[rowCount].FindControl("lblAwardName")).Text, out cell1Val);
            Int32.TryParse(((TextBox)ESBAndTSRValuesInputGridView.Rows[rowCount].FindControl("ESBValue")).Text, out cell2Val);
            Int32.TryParse(((TextBox)ESBAndTSRValuesInputGridView.Rows[rowCount].FindControl("TSRValue")).Text, out cell3Val);
            Int32.TryParse(ESBAndTSRValuesInputGridView.Rows[rowCount].Cells[3].Text, out cell3Val);

            int val1 = Int32.Parse(ESBAndTSRValuesInputGridView.Rows[rowCount].Cells[0].Text);
            int val2 = Int32.Parse(dr["AWARDID"].ToString());

            if (val1 == val2)
            {
                rowIndex = rowCount;
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Cells 0 and 1 are for the BoundFields, which have not ID. So how can it work for those ?

Comment: you have to find control to get values from asp control which are child of grid view ..you can not get value directly..first two are not control they are boundfield

Comment: So how do I get the value for the BoundFields then, as that's what I really want ?

Comment: You forgot to mention the `runat="server"` statement for the two labels you created .. But other than that, it works fine ! :) .. I would suggest you add the `runat="server"` for the two labels too, just in case someone else comes along this answer and it doesn't work for them just the way you've currently written it ..